# How to open a local file in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

In Google Chrome's minimalist brilliance, they seem to have forgotten a menu item to launch a dialog box to open a local file.

How to get around this?

I don't want to drag local files onto the Chrome window (which works) or type file:// in the address bar (also works). I want my dialog box

Comment: Out of curiousity, why did you delete your original answer?

Comment: Indeed, your solution was so elegantly simple :).

Comment: I wanted to share the wealth.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On OS X, you can choose "Open File" from the File menu, or use the <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

For Windows and Linux, you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>. This does not seem to be referenced anywhere in the application, so you can feel special about using it.

Comment: There is no menu for Chrome. At least not on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why I forgot that. Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

According to [the Chrome Help Pages](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99438) there are three ways to do this:

> 1. Press Ctrl+O on your keyboard and
>      browse for the file on your
>      computer.
> 2. Drag the file into Google
>      Chrome from your computer desktop or
>      folder. Your cursor displays a
>      little '+' sign if the action is
>      successful.
> 3. Type the location, also
>      known as the path, of the file in
>      the address bar, then press Enter.

Comment: wait a second ... there are Chrome help pages??? :)

Comment: Just press F1 to get to them.

Answer (score 2):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> and a magical, undocumented dialog box will appear.

Comment: That's also the same shortcut for the other browsers of choice.

Comment: Sure didn't leave any time between asking and answering.

Answer (score 2):

Use Url Alias extension.
Under "Alias" enter a/ or ag/ or b/  etc
Under "Redirect To" dialog enter path to file

file:///C:/etc

Moreover it is a very handy extension in itself